# iframe src on another server

Tags: html, wamp

I have an intranet site running on our web server but then I have a seperate WAMP server that I have some forms located on. I want to insert the form on the intranet site within an iframe however I can't figure out what to put in for the source. I tried using the same url I've used to access and test the forms on their own but that isn't working and I receive a page cannot be displayed message within the iframe.

Here is my HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="wamp/setupform"></iframe>
```

Because it is on a different server is there another step I need to take?

Comment: what do you meany by not working?

Comment: It gives me a page cannot be displayed in the iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL pointing to a different hostname must start with a scheme (e.g. `http://`) or be scheme-relative (and start with `//`).

Comment: Worked! Thanks. I will accept this as the answer when it will allow me to.